# How to enable extension=fileinfo.so in my shared hosting?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, shared-hosting, php-ini

This error message appeared when I tried to upload an image on my shared hosting: "PHP Fileinfo extension must be installed/enabled to use Intervention Image". I then modified my php.ini settings using .htaccess.

Now my .htaccess file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/public_html/subfolder
    </IfModule>    
    </IfModule>
```

The subfolder specified in the .htaccess file is where my Laravel project is located, and it's where I want to serve my application.

To enable PHPFileinfo, I wrote the following code in the php.ini file located in the project root:

```
extension=fileinfo.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

It's not working on my shared hosting!

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a technical 
support question that should be directed to your web host.

Comment: You can contact with your hosting provider.

Comment: I already contact to hosting provider after that I give the post.

Answer (score 6):

You can enable fileinfo extension from cpanel 1 Go to SOFTWARE=>Select PHP Version=>fileinfo check box and enable fileinfo extension.[image]

Comment: I have enabled it my this method but it doesnt work on my side. should Icontact with your hosting provider?

Answer (score 2):

Your host provider need to have the extension file in their php config so it can't be done from your side .

Answer (score 1):

You can enable fileinfo extension from cpanel
1 .Go to SOFTWARE=>
2. Select PHP Version=>fileinfo check box and enable fileinfo extension.
3. refresh your website and thats all.

Comment: This did for me, so we vote it up :)